# how to put data write break point in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++

I am debugging piece of code in visual studio 2008 , while running the programe throws a bufferover run , i want to test the variables using data write breakpoints , can some one tell me how to put data write breakpoints on variables

Comment: Read/write breakpoints are usually implemented as hardware breakpoints and, as such, require the addresses to be known at compile-time. This is - at least to my knowledge - impossible with automatic variables.

Comment: Are we talking about automatic variables? He can first use a regular breakpoint to determine the address and then place the data breakpoint. See Hans Passant's answer.

Comment: Since Visual Studio 2005 you can utilize also the /GS compiler switch, which provides buffer overflow protection with canary words: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). If you use that feature, the buffer overflow will cause an exception in the end and you can break on that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been more practical if you gave a code snippet.  I'm forced to make my own:

```
void foo() {
    int ix = 0x42;
    int jx;
    long long* p = (long long*)&ix;
    *p = 0x100000042LL;
}
```

This intentional stack corruption attempt will break the debugger:

[image]

So I set a breakpoint at function entry and set a data breakpoint after the address of variable "ix" with Debug + New Breakpoint + New Data Breakpoint:

[image]

And press F5 to continue running.  The data breakpoint triggers:

[image]

Comment: Nice screenshots! I would add that in my experience a data breakpoint significantly slows down the debugged program. But that can be really acceptable trade-off in favor of finding a bug.

Comment: It doesn't slow down anything.  They are implemented by the processor with the debugging registers.  The reason you can only ever set four of them.  Conditional breakpoints can cause slow down.

Comment: Hand Passant's gave use ful info , thanks i am satisfied , i cant voter your answer as I am a new user,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use WinDbg. Visual Studio is not very good on breaking on data writes or data reads. You can get WinDbg for free from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx You can find extensive help online for WinDbg, including how to use it to break on data point reads, read/writes, or just writes. Microsoft provides links from the URL I listed, and http://windbg.info has a lot of information on using WinDbg.

However, if you insist on using Visual Studio 2008, the way to do this is to start the program under your the Visual Studio debugger. Set a break point in the code where the variable you are interested in is active. Once the debugger breaks the execution at your breakpoint, you can add a new breakpoint on the variable read or write using the "new breakpoint" menu. You may need to select the variable you are interested in and then use the context select to start the "new breakpoint". Select "Datapoint access", and select whether it is for read or write or read/write access.

For more details, consult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0(v=VS.90).aspx